# How to use Newton Raphson in mathmatica

Tags: nonlinear

I want to plot with area ratio and Mach number. In the problem the equation form is nonlinear, so i used the findroot for using newton-Raphson.(convergent & divergent nozzle)

But, the solutions are only one at each area ratio.
I know that each area ratio have two mach number

i.e. i want to get two solution at each point with using newton-Raphson.

in addition, how about use NSolve??

my code is

```
r:=1.4
eq:=a==1/M ((2/(r+1))(1+(r-1)/2 M^2)^(r+1)/2(r-1)
Data1:=Table[FindRoot[eq/.a->n,{M,0.1}],{n,1,10,0.5}]
list1:=M/.Data1
ListLinePlot[List1,PlotRange->{0,4},Mesh->All]
```

Comment: are you sure your equation has the right form. I see there are issues with paranthesis

Comment: `FindRoot[]` will only find one solution. You would have to use it twice, with different starting points.  `NSolve[]` will return all roots (usually). If there are always two real roots, then try this: `Transpose@Table[M /. NSolve[eq /. a -> n, M, Reals], {n, 1, 10, 0.5}]`

Comment: for sure that last group `(r+1)/2(r-1)` should  be `((r+1)/2/(r-1))`

Comment: Thank you, it is what i want !!!